# Why STL map's method "find" raise "core dumped" with the std::bitset type key?

Tags: c++, dictionary, g++, bitset

I try to use `std::bitset` to be my map's key. But it raise `core dumped` when it run on the `map.find()`.

here is my code:

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

template<size_t N> struct bitset_less{
    bool operator() (const std::bitset<N>& a, const std::bitset<N>& b) const {
        for(size_t i = N - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            if(a[i] ^ b[i]){
                if(a[i]) return false;
                else return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
};


int main(){
    map<bitset<256>, int, bitset_less<256>> m;
    m[bitset<256>(0)] = 0;
    cout << (m.find(bitset<256>(0)) == m.end()?"yes":"no") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I make a struct `bitset_less` to make my map know which `bitset` is bigger and which is smaller(it can help map to build its tree).

`gcc version: 8.3.0`

Thanks a lot ;_;

Comment: by the way, the shell echo useless string like this: `zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out`

Comment: If `i == 0` and you subtract 1 from it, what is the new value of `i`?

Comment: @John Why not make from this an answer ? `i` as size_t, as unsigned int, cannot be negative.

Comment: @rafix07 feel free to make an answer. I'm too sleepy.

Comment: thinks your answers, you help me a lot!